# Why there are so many python versions in use?

Tags: python

I'm new to python world. I started to use https://www.pythonanywhere.com and at some point if asks me to select python version which I want:

> Select a Python version
>
> » Python 2.7
>
> » Python 3.4
>
> » Python 3.5
>
> » Python 3.6
>
> » Python 3.7

For me this is similar to:

> What hammer do you want to hit this nail? Version "oldest", "newer", "the newest"?
>
> Of course "the newest"! Why would I use some old crap?

So (unless there are some compatibility mater in my nail to be hit) why would I want to use an old version of python?

Comment: yep!  https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-370/

Comment: "So (unless there are some compatibility mater in my nail to be hit) why would I want to use an old version of python?"-- no reason, use the latest version unless compatibility is the issue. Python is popular and regularly updated so it's not surprising there are many versions

Comment: As a beginner, _you_ certainly shouldn't use anything but the latest (unless you're tied to hardware/OSs that aren't supported by newer versions). However, there are decades of legacy python code/libraries/applications out there, so there are many reasons why somebody else might need to stick with old versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you don't have compatibility requirements, just use the newest stable version. There are lots and lots of applications out there that have such compatibility problems.